# Why do I see strange curves on canvas when drawing solid lines?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am making some code just for fun and I noticed a strange detail. I have canvas and here is code that draws lines in it.
Here is example: https://jsfiddle.net/vladyslavkushney/mf3p5e2n/

```
for (let y = 0; y < 400; y++) {
    drawLine(0, 200, 400, y);    
}
/* ... */
var drawLine = (fromX, fromY, toX, toY) => {
    ctx.beginPath();    
    ctx.moveTo(fromX, fromY);
    ctx.lineTo(toX, toY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

So simply it is drawing 400 lines from (0, 200) to each of (400, y).
As result it is triangle. And what I see looks this:

[image: canvas image]

I am curious why I see strange curves at right side but not a solid red triangle?

Comment: It could be an aliasing effect as the lines overlap on the edges. Accelerated graphics may render pixels based on a float position, and "mixes" the result best it can. Also, while the colors overlap from the starting point, the end points are far enough away that the lines don't exactly line up side by side (hence the pattern). I'm only guessing though. ;)

Comment: Opened screenshow in paint - ligher color is RGB(252,53,53), while darker is regualr RGB(254,0,0). Thats really strange. But probably browser render engine mixes white background with red lines, as distance between lines grows to the right.

Comment: Yeah, me theory works - when changed background color of canvas to black, "lighter" areas switched to being "darker". https://jsfiddle.net/mf3p5e2n/17/. So, browser takes into account background color when anti-aliasing lines, so picture we see is result of specific algorithm of lines anti-aliasing lines.

Comment: [Moire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern)

Comment: some of these comments are the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The curves you see are aliasing artifacts. When each line is drawn, it is antialiased but this is done relative to the fuzzy edges of the line before it.

Consequently, there is an artifact created as each line's fuzzy edges are merged into a more and more red colour until they peak at halfway between red and white when the line is totally horizontal. The near-horizontal lines also nearly totally cover up their previously drawn neighbours, creating the pinkish void.